# Drupal—Content Repetition & Consistency

Tags: drupal

I'm currently working on a Drupal site (I'm fairly new to Drupal) and need to be able to create some blocks of content that appear on multiple pages and remain consistent between those pages. I'll need it so that if I change the content in one place, the change will be reflected in all places it appears.

I've looked around in CCK a bit but can't seem to find a way to accomplish this there. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Drupal, like all CMSes, does this out of the box. Can you provide more detail about what you've tried and why you believe it doesn't work?

Comment: I've mainly just tried to use CCK to accomplish this. As I'll need bits of identical content on like pages I attempted to create a content type in CCK and create a default value. I tried creating a page based on this content type, edited the default value in CCK controls, but no changes were reflected on the page. I guess beyond that I'm not sure where to go.... Thanks!

Comment: The default value is used in the form when the node is created, it is not meant for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own blocks at `/admin/build/block/add`, just put your content inside a block and then go to "page specific visibility settings" and put the pages, on which the block should appear there.

There are other ways to achieve something like you describe, if the blocks don't do what you need you should provide some more details on what exactly you want to do. Depending on the structure of your site, you could also use a node (set to appear at the top of lists) that is set to appear on those pages.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend of what kind of data you need to display in this block if its static use

> /admin/build/block/add

if you intend to fetch some content from your content types use views to create such block and then use "page specific visibility settings".